# web2py: change default controller and function

Tags: python, web2py

It looks pretty straightforward to update default controller and function by web2py online book  http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/04#URL . Here is what I did in routes.py of myapplication

```
default_application = "myapplication"       
default_controller = "mycontroller"
default_function = "home" 
BASE =''
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = "myapplication",       
        default_controller = "mycontroller",
        default_function = "home",      
        )

)
```

But it didn't work. Something I am missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just use this part:

```
routers = dict(
    BASE = dict(
        default_application = "myapplication",       
        default_controller = "mycontroller",
        default_function = "home",
        functions = ['other', 'functions', 'in', 'default', 'controller'],
        )  
)
```

Note, you should list the other functions in the default controller so the router will still be able to remove the default function name even when there are other args in the URL.

Answer (score 2):

routes.py is only read at the time your web2py server process starts.  If you edit the file, you will need to restart web2py for it to take effect.  This is a "gotcha" since in many other contexts, web2py reloads .py files upon update.  Not so for routes.py and a few other special files; and module files too (by default).